# Flask can not be accessed on other computers in the LAN

Tags: python

My code is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World!'

@app.route('/user/<user>')
def user(user):
    return user

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

Can be accessed on the machine, but other computers in the LAN can not be accessed.
What does my local computer need to set up?

Comment: You may need to check your firewall settings

Comment: I have closed the firewall, but still can not access. @bakatrouble